# Unable to get textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am using onClick event to get the value from text area. 
 If i use below code it returns html not the value as below :

```
$(this).find(".button2").click(function($e) {
    var comment_content = $(this).find('textarea[name="comment_content"]').val();
    console.log(comment_content);
});
```

output :

```
<textarea class="styledtextarea" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"></textarea>
```

Even If i give any any value in text area still i see empty.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="">
<div class="">
<form id="" class="">
<div class="">
    <p></p>
    <div id="" class="">
        <div class="" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="" class="">
    <p><b></b></p>


        <textarea class="styledtextarea" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" ></textarea>

        <a  href="#" class="button2" type="submit"><span><b>Send<b></span></a>

    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to add a bit more of the HTML?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce.](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljn5a888/).

Comment: Petrichor is right. The problem isn't with the code in the question. Voting to close.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/yauL2z5y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `this` in the `click` callback function you are referencing the object that triggered the `click` event, in this case `.button2`.

When you do `var comment_content = $(this).find('textarea[name="comment_content"]').val();` you are actually searching for `textarea[name="comment_content"]` in the `.button2` element.

What you need to do is this:

```
$(".button2").click(function($e) {
    var comment_content = $('textarea[name="comment_content"]').val();
    console.log(comment_content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
   var comment_content = $(this).find("textarea#comment_content").val();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JS code, the textarea is a child element of the button, which I'm sure is not the case.

Try this code instead (don't use the .find() method on $(this) to find the textarea):

```
$(this).find(".button2").click(function($e) {
                        var comment_content = $("#comment_content").val();
                console.log(comment_content);
```

});